# React const not returning anything

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I had this hardcoded code:

```
 <div className="box e">
                <div data-testid="todo-1" className="username">
                    ApooBG
                </div>

                <div className="progress">
                    <img src={require('./images/rabbit.png')} style={{ left: progressOfUser(percentageOfText()) + '%' }} />
                    <hr />
                </div>

                <div className="finishedText">
                    {percentageOfText()}
                </div>
                <div className="username">
                    Paffkas
                </div>

                <div className="progress">
                    <img src={require('./images/raccoon.png')} style={{ left: -50 + '%' }} />
                    <hr />
                </div>

                <div className="finishedText">
                    0
                </div>
                <div className="username">
                    PetarGH2
                </div>

                <div className="progress">
                    <img src={require('./images/eagle.png')} style={{ left: -50 + '%' }} />
                    <hr />
                </div>

                <div className="finishedText">
                    0
                </div>
                <div className="username">
                    Gonzales
                </div>

                <div className="progress">
                    <img src={require('./images/fox.png')} style={{ left: -50 + '%' }} />
                    <hr />
                </div>

                <div className="finishedText">
                    0
                </div>
                <div className="username">
                    Average
                </div>

                <div className="progress">
                    <img src={require('./images/rabbit.png')} style={{ left: progressOfUser(percentageOfText() / 4) + '%' }} />
                    <hr />
                </div>

                <div className="finishedText">
                    {percentageOfText() / 4}
                </div>
            </div>
```

and the box looked like that:
[image]

then, I wanted to transfer everything from the database and not hard-coded, so I implemented this method:

```
const Players = () => {
        const url = "https://localhost:7101/GetPlayersInMain";
        fetch(url)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                data.forEach((el) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="box e">
                            <div className="username">
                                {el.Username}
                            </div>

                            <div className="progress">
                                <img src={require('./images/raccoon.png')} style={{ left: progressOfUser(el.WPM) + '%' }} />
                                <hr />
                            </div>

                            <div className="finishedText">
                                {el.WPM}
                                {console.log(el)}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            })
    }


    return (
 <div className="box e">
            {Players()}
                <div className="username">
                    Average
                </div>

                <div className="progress">
                    <img src={require('./images/rabbit.png')} style={{ left: progressOfUser(percentageOfText() / 4) + '%' }} />
                    <hr />
                </div>

                <div className="finishedText">
                    {percentageOfText() / 4}
                </div>
            </div>
);
}
```

and this is the result:
[image]

I have a console.log in the foreach and it returns the right result:
[image]
so there should be two more people than just the hard-coded average. I tried different methods, different div tags and different calls of the method but nothing worked. Here are the two problems:

1. It doesn't return anything for some reason and that's the main issue!
2. And it gets called out many times for some reason, which could slow the app? So how can I fix that
   [image]

Comment: you can use useEffect to fetch data useEffect(() => { Players () } , [])  and  set the value in a useState after getting resonse for api

Comment: Dude checkout out some article on [how to fetch data](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/fetch-data-react/) in React

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not render the `.then` of an API call like this.

A common pattern to do this is to utilize the `useEffect` to fetch the data in combination with the `useState` to store the result which should be displayed.

Inside your component you could add 3 things:

1. A state to store the results from your database

`const [state, setState] = useState([])`

2. A call to the API

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const url = "https://localhost:7101/GetPlayersInMain";
  fetch(URL)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    setState(data);
  }   
}, [])
```

3. use the state in your component

replace the `{Players()}` with

```
{data.map(el => {
  console.log(el);
  return (
    <div className="box e">
      <div className="username">
        {el.Username}
      </div>

      <div className="progress">
        <img src={require('./images/raccoon.png')} style={{ left: progressOfUser(el.WPM) + '%' }} />
        <hr />
       </div>

      <div className="finishedText">
        {el.WPM}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
})};
```